# UV mapping PS to Blender

Tags: modeling, uv-image-editor

I've imported my texture onto my mesh which is UV unwrapped (Lots of Booleans were used) the text appears on the UV, but it wont appear in the viewports. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Ah ok, Iw as missing the texture node.  I added the texture node, the texture appeared on the UV map, but it came out black and pixelated, but the font colour is white, how can I get my font white and non pixelated?

https://ibb.co/Y05zrk3

Comment: Hello :). You shouldn't run the *Image Texture* through the *Noise Texture* :). What is the purpose of the noise texture? Perhaps there's a better way to combine it.

Comment: Hi Jachym, thanks for replying.

I use noise texture because electronic devices have a bit of noise on their materials which break up that clean look of plastic or metal. Because when I use a plain colour on any surface it looks unrealistic. so I was seeing various tutorials which add noise texture to give devices a feeling of a realism. If you have another method, I'd appreciate to see how to achieve this.

Thank you.

Comment: can you notice the noise vs no noise, the bottom image just looks too smooth.

https://ibb.co/6DyP2bJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't combine image and noise texture that way.
If you need a non-smooth surface, just use it as a *Bump map*.

1. Connect image texture into Base Color input
2. Use *Noise texture* with the *Bump node* and connect it into *Height*
3. Connect the *Bump node* into Normal input

[image]

**Other observations:**

- avoid n-gons, they cause bad shading and prevent loopcuts, proper beveling, etc.
- use linked duplicates - similar buttons can share the same mesh yet be independently moved/rotated
- the main area has 3.74° tilt. Make sure your buttons are tilted consistently.
- don't plug *Noise texture* node into the *Specular input*, if you're going for realism.
- Avoid extreme values in the *Noise texture*. Use *White Noise* for fine grain.

*Use quads (and tris) when possible.*

[image]

Comment: I did add the Nodes, and worked well the text coming through, but unfortunately the UV mapping of the text, has gone out of place, and cannot figure out why this is happening since Ive used as a template the UV which I exported... I added the UI elements in Adobe, then exported as a PNG file. When applied within Blender, the text wont fall in place on my UV projected from view mesh. What am I doing wrong?

https://ibb.co/9wBK257

Comment: @blenderbreath Oh, this is simple :). Your image is non-square. So either export it from AI as a square (reccomended), or just unwrap your keyboard again (it will respect the new aspect ratio):).

Comment: Ok thanks for the insight, I'll try again, because I'm doing something wrong although I'm trying your methods. I'll post again shortly, after I see the new results.

Comment: For some reason my UV is stretching from square to rectangle. My PNG file is 1024 x 1024 when exported. But its not adapting to my UV mesh. I'm happy to share my file if you think you can take a closer look to this problem. 

Thank you.

https://ibb.co/YD7rBFY

Comment: Sure, share the .blend and I'll take a look when i get home :).

Comment: Ok great, thanks heaps, appreciate it. Hopefully it's something minor. Ill upload the file and Ill see it in the morning.

Thank you.

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=Qx3aoGwj" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/Qx3aoGwj/)

Comment: Hi. The layout image doesn't seem to be packed in the file :). Can you please share it separately?

Comment: Ah, I thought the image text would be included... But here it is uploaded:

https://ibb.co/pysQ0sk

Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105601/discussion-between-jachym-michal-and-blender-breath).